# Jar in external libraries but cannot import in code

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, java-module

(more info at bottom)

I am using Maven to fetch the MySQL Connector for java

```xml
dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.16</version>
</dependency>
```

As such, it shows up in my External Libraries (intellij)

[image: screenshot of external libraries (intellij)]

However, in my code, I cannot import `java.sql.*`, as java.sql is not an option.

[image: screenshot of failed java.sql import]

In addition, I have made sure that my Project Structure is correct, having the dependency set as Compile scope

[image: screenshot of project structure]

I have also invalidated cache.

I have been stuck on this issue for a bit and cannot find a resolution; any help is appreciated.

More info: java.sql
Works in java 8 projects
Works in blank java 12 projects (not created with openjfx 12 archetype)

Inside main I now have this line of code:

```
java.sql.Connection c = null;
```

The error message I get when running is:

```
Error:(37, 9) java: package java.sql is not visible
  (package java.sql is declared in module java.sql, but module com.github.phaserush does not read it)
```

Comment: Java 12? Then the sql module probably needs to be enabled.

Comment: The java.sql package is in the JDK itself. You can import classes fro this package,  whether or not you have the mysql driver (which is only necessary at **runtime** to connect to MySQL).

Comment: Thanks to you both for your comments. @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen  how would i enable the module?

Comment: and @JBNizet would you know why i cant write /import java.sql ?

Comment: You can. Just write it. Then compile your code. And if it doesn't compile, you'll have an error message explaining what the problem is. Then read/post the error message if you can't understand it.

Comment: @JBNizet alright, updated with the error. Thanks

Comment: @JBNizet If the OP is using modular code, then he will need to explicitly add the module `java.sql` to his `module-info.java`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel can you link to an example to what youre talking about? I want to give it a try.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks. I suspected that kind of problem, but I don't know the module system yet. Having an error message clearly showing what the problem is helps.

Comment: @JBNizet "javax.sql" not being present is a very strong hint that this is the new module system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error indicates you are using the Java module system, and the `java.sql` module (containing packages `java.sql` and `javax.sql`) is not part of the default set of modules loaded by Java. You will need to explicitly depend on it.

In your `src/main/java` edit your `module-info.java` and add `requires java.sql;`. For example:

```
module com.github.phaserush {
    requires java.sql;
}
```

Where `com.github.phaserush` is your module name based on the exception message in your question.